# Clicking on image results in an error: Element is not clickable at point (97, 421)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to edit the line item in the grid. When I try to click on edit image icon, it shows the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (97, 421). Other element would receive the click: <div unselectable="on" class="Somevalue" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 3000; background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170); opacity: 0.5; width: 958px; height: 671px;"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=34.0.1847.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 44 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:33:32'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Session ID: a379df9abbfb4b23c1aeffbe5563f2b1
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\ARUNKU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir5576_16596}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=34.0.1847.131, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
    at login_check.login.testLoginCheck(login.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Following is HTML code snippet:

```
<td>
 <input type="image" name="grdHospitalizationHistory$ctl00$ctl04$gbcEditRows" id="grdHospitalizationHistory_ctl00_ctl04_gbcEditRows" title="Edit" src="Resources/edit.gif" alt="Edit" style="border-width:0px;">
</td>
```

And, following is the Selenium code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("grdHospitalizationHistory$ctl00$ctl04$gbcDeleteRows"‌​)).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Please post HTML code snippet and your code whatever you tried to click on image.

Comment: This is my code driver.findElement(By.name("grdHospitalizationHistory$ctl00$ctl04$gbcDeleteRows")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); and HTML "<td><input type="image" name="grdHospitalizationHistory$ctl00$ctl04$gbcEditRows" id="grdHospitalizationHistory_ctl00_ctl04_gbcEditRows" title="Edit" src="Resources/edit.gif" alt="Edit" style="border-width:0px;"></td>"

Comment: Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: Please go through the answer I posted.

Comment: I used explicit wait code and download the latest version 2.10 but still I am getting same error.

Comment: Did you try with `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52363/discussion-between-tdhm-and-arun-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, it can be resolved by one of the following ways:

1. If you're running your tests against Chrome, make sure that your'e using chromedriver's latest version.(This might solve the problem)
2. Use explicit wait before clicking on the element. This is because click action is performed before image is loaded.

Comment: I tried your solution ,but still I am getting same error.Can you give me anyother solution? my code is WebDriverWait Edit_wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
 Edit_wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='grdHospitalizationHistory_ctl00_ctl04_gbcEditRows']")));
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='grdHospitalizationHistory_ctl00_ctl04_gbcEditRows']")).click();

Comment: Please try with `WebElement element = Edit_wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id‌​='grdHospitalizationHistory_ctl00_ctl04_gbcEditRows']")); element.click(); `

Comment: I have tried your code.Its not working. but when I debug,the values get edited.when I run my code,it shows same error.What may be the problem?